# Running VBA code across multiple sheets in a workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I use the below code that utilizes the sheet "Previous Week apps" for data collection and updates the count in the same sheet.

I have created a button and i'm trying to run this code through the button.

On execution i get the error as "Object required" in line

```
[W5] = wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Trophy")
```

My code:

```
Sub Prevcount()

 Sheets("Previous Week apps")

 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Previous week apps")
  [W5] = wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Trophy")
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Previous week apps")
[W7] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("I:I"), "Trophy", .Range("E:E"), "COMPATIBLE")
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Previous week apps")
[W9] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("I:I"), "Trophy", .Range("F:F"), "COMPATIBLE")
End With

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Previous week apps")
[W11] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("I:I"), "Trophy", .Range("Q:Q"), "UG")
End With

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you intend `Sheets("Previous Week apps")` to be `With Sheets("Previous Week apps")` (to match up with the `End With` at the end of your code) and, if so, what are you doing with that `With` block - there is nothing in your code that is making use of it.

Comment: @YowE3K So i should change it to `with Sheets("Previous Week apps")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the short version (replaced `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` , where you have your code):

```
Sub Prevcount()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Previous week apps")
  .Range("W5").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Trophy")
  .Range("W7").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("I:I"), "Trophy", .Range("E:E"), "COMPATIBLE")
  .Range("W9").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("I:I"), "Trophy", .Range("F:F"), "COMPATIBLE")
  .Range("W11").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("I:I"), "Trophy", .Range("Q:Q"), "UG")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting object required error in `.Range("W5").Value = wf.CountIf(.Range("I:I"), "Trophy")`